# Data recovery from broken Ubuntu

Tags: boot, data-recovery

I had a problem with the ubuntu on my pc. it suddenly stopped booting by start up. I made a portable ubuntu and now I am operating from usb drive. my question is how can I have access to the data on my hard disk while operating from the ubuntu portable copy.
thanks

Comment: Need to give more information on what version of Ubuntu you are using.  Regardless, if the hard drive is functioning, you should be able to mount it when loading the Live USB.   It is possible, however, that you stopped being able to boot because the disk stopped working (not being able to see it when booting from USB may also suggest the same).

Comment: the live Ubuntu is 16.04.3 but the old corrupted one was 14--- when I installed it but I installed updates as well.

Comment: the hard disk is functioning and when I press with the right mouse button on the hard disk icon on the side bar I can see that there is an unmount possibility. but the problem is when I am trying to access any file on the user directory from the corrupted system I get the messege that I have no permission to access this directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mount the partition that holds the data on your hard disk. For example if your data partition is `/dev/sda2`, then you have to run `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/sda2` from the terminal. You can then `cd` to `/media/sda2` and access your data. This is assuming you didn't use an LVM and encrypt your `/` or `/home` directories upon initial install.

Comment: Hi hamiheim, thanks for your answer. what if I dont know on wich partition my data are on. is there an easy way to mount the partition. although I can see it on the side bar and when I open any files for example the folder with the name of the user name from the corrupted old Ubuntu OP I get a message that I have no permission to open this directory.

Comment: you can mount the partition using the command listed above. See if you can get to the directory from the terminal as root after it's mounted. If it still says denied, chances are you encrypted it when you set it up, and then you're SOL.